# .htaccess Page Redirect is Having Effect on AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am working on social networking site that works like Facebook. Posts are displayed on the home page. They can be liked and commented on. 
If a post is liked, the **LIKE TABLE** gets updated via AJAX and have its like count incremented by one. The `likes.php` file updates the 
LIKE TABLE and returns the incremented value, `<span class = 'likeCount'>. $likeCount .</span>`, and have it appended to the like button.

This works fine in `home.php` but not on `user.php` which is the user profile page. The `user.php` fetches posts that are only related to a specific user. You get PHP errors
whenever you try to like or comment on a post in `user.php` page. When I `alert( msg );` it shows the entire HTML code of the requesting page, `user.php` with PHP errors that some variables are undefined. The URL is actually like this `http://localhost/mysite/user.php?userID=yax` but it is redirected and rewritten by .htaccess as `http://localhost/mysite/user/yax`. I guess it is the one causing the problem because the same AJAX is working fine in home.php.

**AJAX code:**

```
$(".mlike").click(function () {
    $(".murconform").submit(function(e){
        return false;
    });
    var $this=$(this);
    var post_id = $(this).val();
    var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
    alert('Post: '+post_id +' User: '+user_id);
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "likes.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { post : post_id , user : user_id },
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function( msg ) {    
        $this.prev('.likecount').html( msg ); 
    });
});
```

**.htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /mysite/user/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

This has really frustrated and halted my work for the past three days. Any help will be appropriately appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any screenshot of firebug>network for your ajax request on user page?

Comment: General tip: If you get error messages, then tell us what they are, and SHOW THE CODE.

Comment: @MarcB: AJAX is returning the HTML of the requesting page.

Answer (score 1):

Since your AJAX call is making POST request you can add a rule to skip POST requests fro rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: However, it is requesting likes.php, so rewrite rule cannot be override likes.php. There is only rule for user.php

Comment: True your rules are only affecting `/user.php?user=something`

Comment: Have just added the rule but AJAX is not working. It only shows the first `alert` and nothing more. I have an `alert( msg);` which is the one showing the returned **HTML** but it is not showing again.

Comment: Actually `RewriteBase` was incorrect that I fixed it. What happens you open `http://domain.com/mysite/likes.php` in your browser?

Comment: @anubhava: After changing the `RewriteBase` to what you said, it says **Not found The requested URL /mysite/user.php was not found on this server.**. And opening `http://domain.com/mysite/likes.php` won't show anything because it is set to execute its codes only if AJAX post values `isset`.

Comment: Is directly entering `http://domain.com/mysite/user.php?user=yax` in the browser not converting the URL to `http://domain.com/mysite/yax`?

Comment: @anubhava: Yes it is.

Comment: **SOLVED!** Moved `likes.php` to **user** folder. Thanks, immeasurably!

Answer (score 1):

Well, try this :

In you .htaccess add this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^post_to_likes$ path/to/likes.php
```

Now within you Javascript code use this :

```
$.post('hxxp://your.url/post_to_likes',data,callback,'html');
```

Comment: "RewriteRule pattern target". Your problem is how to tell the browser where and how to find your script file. Try this code, it is safe.

Comment: is your script "likes.php" located in "/mysite/user/" ?

Comment: NO! It is not. Could that have been the cause?

Comment: try to call : you url/path/to/likes.php directly from the browser, what happens ?

Comment: **SOLVED!** Moved `likes.php` to **user** folder. Thanks, immeasurably!

Comment: In the absence of acceptable answer, how can one change the status to solved?